# Fill buttons in grid with FontAwesome icons and add tooltips to them

Tags: java, vaadin, font-awesome

Is there any way to use FontAwesome for buttons in Grid? I tried to make it as an html - but buttos dont parse html but I can only see it as text.
I also tried to make a custom renderer (from https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/9418390/9765924) but it does not work - no errors, it just wont change text no matter how i do it.

I would like to have 3 buttons with FontAwesome icons and tooltips in every row. Is there some simple way to do that?

Comment: any particular reason none of the answers is good enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you want is clickable icons that don't necessarily need to be buttons.

So instead of using `ButtonRenderer` to add buttons, for which you can only provide a caption, a simple solution is to use `HtmlRenderer` to add the FontAwesome icon (1 column for each icon), then use an `ItemClickListener`.  Use `ItemClickEvent#getPropertyId()` to detect which column was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I've a simple workaround for the FontIcon issue.

I've used a normal ButtonRenderer and I've overridden the getValue() method of PropertyValueGenerator object to return the icon codepoint.

```
 wrapperContainer.addGeneratedProperty("delete", new PropertyValueGenerator<String>() {
        @Override
        public String getValue(Item item, Object itemId, Object propertyId) {
            return "\uF014"; //FontAwesome.TRASH_O
        }

        @Override
        public Class<String> getType() {
            return String.class;
        }
    });
```

I've put in scss the right font-family for button element:

```
button {
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-size: 25px;
  color: $v-blue-color;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Pure-Java solution for Vaadin 8:

```
    final ButtonRenderer<Person> renderer = new ButtonRenderer<>(event -> onPersonClicked(event.getItem()));
    renderer.setHtmlContentAllowed(true);
    grid.addColumn(person -> VaadinIcons.EXTERNAL_BROWSER.getHtml(), renderer).setWidth(60);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of alternative
Like add with HtmlRenderer or CellStyleGenerator and anothers
But HtmlRenderer uploading for every row like this data

```
25=<span class="v-icon v-icon-caret_square_up_o" style="font-family: Vaadin-Icons;">&#xe7c2;</span>
```

This is big problem for network traffic
So I like to use

```
Grid.Column gridColumn = grid.addColumn(a -> (char) FontAwesome.BTC.getCodepoint());
gridColumn.setStyleGenerator(item -> "cssStyleName");
```

With this network usage is better as you see

```
27= //unshowing character is icon character code
```

but don't forget to add     "cssStyleName" to css / for example

```
.cssStyleName {font-family: FontAwesome; }
```

And listen clicks with

```
grid.addItemClickListener(event -> {
   if (!event.getMouseEventDetails().isDoubleClick()) {
       //To Do
   }
}
```

This is compatible with Vaadin 8

Answer (score -2):

A button with just an icon and a tooltip can be created like this:

```
Button button = new Button(FontAwesome.ANDROID);
button.setDescription("Any tooltip");
```

To generate buttons for each row, just use any fitting loop (for or while).

Comment: Problem is that a renderer is needed to fill buttons into grid in Vaadin. This renderer can only take the button caption - for one button.